# Error assigned data must be compatible with existing data

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable, "F", by adding columns (B+C+D+E) if the column "A" is 1.

| ID | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 1 | 2 | NA | 1 |
| 002 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | NA |

```
df$F <- rowSums(df[df$A == '1', c(3:6)],na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get this error:

```
Error:
! Assigned data `rowSums(df[df$A == "1", c(3:6)], na.rm = TRUE)` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 12358 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 474 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Backtrace:
  1. base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, F, value = `<dbl>`)
 12. tibble (local) `<fn>`(`<vctrs___>`)
 Error:
```

How can I fix this?  Are there other ways to get my final outcome something looks like the one below?

| ID | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 1 | 2 | NA | 1 | 4 |
| 002 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | NA | NA |

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
df$F <- ifelse(df$A == 1, rowSums(df[, c("B", "C", "D", "E")], na.rm=TRUE), NA)
df
#   ID A B C  D  E  F
# 1  1 1 1 2 NA  1  4
# 2  2 0 2 1  1 NA NA
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, actually I'm in favor of `==`, and since the result is the same even with `NA` in `A`, I edited according to your suggestion (akrun's answer would fail with `NA` in `A`). However, compare `c(1, 0, NA) %in% 1` and `c(1, 0, NA) == 1`. So the reason why `F` gets an `NA` in my answer is different, hence my earlier note about it. But I agree that it is much better to teach `==`.

Comment: You’re right that the behaviour in the presence of NAs is different. However, I actually think that this makes using `%in%` in this scenario even worse, since casual readers (even those experienced in R!) will *expect* the semantics to be identical. In my view NAs are both one of the best and worst facets of R: in my own code I always try handling them explicitly; where I don’t that’s an oversight (and potential bug) 10 times out of 10.

Answer (score 0):

We just need the logical to be on the lhs as well to keep the lengths same

```
df$F[df$A == '1'] <- rowSums(df[df$A == '1', c(3:6)],na.rm=TRUE)
```

-output

```
> df
  ID A B C  D  E  F
1  1 1 1 2 NA  1  4
2  2 0 2 1  1 NA NA
```

Comment: Why does this work if F doesn't exist yet and actually LHS `df$F[df$A %in% '1']` gives `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach:

#### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### Data

```
data <-
tibble::tribble(
    ~ID, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D, ~E,
  "001", 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L,
  "002", 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA
  )
```

#### Code

```
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(`F` = if_else(A == 1, sum(c_across(cols = B:E),na.rm = TRUE), NA_integer_) )
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  ID        A     B     C     D     E     F
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 001       1     1     2    NA     1     4
2 002       0     2     1     1    NA    NA
```

Comment: No need (and no reason!) to backtick-quote the name `F`. Backtick quotes are only necessary for non-syntactic names (e.g. names containing spaces or special characters).